# Tastypie how to raise errors from my models correctly back to the user?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm using [Tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) to create a user via an API call *(see the api.py below)*. Any error triggers same `except IntegrityError` as you can see. I would like for my model to rise the correct error messages back to the user. Example see the model manager below, when a email is blank the error 'The given email must be set' should be give back to the user as an IntegrityError error.

How should I do this?

**api.py**

```
class CreateResource(ModelResource):
    """
    API Facet that creates and returns a new user with self.user_email
    as login and self.user_password as password.
    """
    class Meta:
        object_class = CompanyUser
        resource_name = 'accounts/create'
        fields = ['password1', 'password2', 'email', 'company']
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        queryset = CompanyUser.objects.all()
        serializer = urlencodeSerializer()

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            CompanyUser.objects.create_user(email=bundle.data['email'],
                                            company=bundle.data['company'],
                                          )

        except IntegrityError:
            raise BadRequest('Username already exists')
```

**Model Manager**

```
class EmailUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves an EmailUser with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = EmailUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=False, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=False, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

As I see it my options are:

1) In the api.py check all parameters one by one (which seems bad as my model does this already) then rise a `IntegrityError` for each issue I have i.e. email blank.

```
if bundle.data['email'] = '':
    raise BadRequest('no email')
```

2) Somehow return back the error from the manager to the api.py file and rise a dynamic IntegrityError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using TastyPie then lookup [validation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html#validation). You can then use your forms.py methods to validate.